# Is there anyway to style select tag?

Tags: html, css

I want to change the arrow size and color. Is there any way doing this with css?

Here's my code;

```
  <div class="gecesayisi">
        <p>Nights</p>
        <select>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="4">5</option>
         </select>

  </div>
```

Select's background is black. In chrome I can't see the arrow but in mozilla I can by the way.

Comment: [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) is your friend.

Comment: Bullet? What bullet? `select`/`option` elements don't have bullets.

Comment: Are you talking about the *arrow* ?

Comment: yes i'm talking about the arrow

Answer (score 2):

There are ways of styling it but it's browser dependant.

Take a [look at this article](http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/) for more information.

```
.styled-select select {
   background: transparent;
   width: 268px;
   padding: 5px;
   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 1;
   border: 0;
   border-radius: 0;
   height: 34px;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.styled-select {
   width: 240px;
   height: 34px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: url(new_arrow.png) no-repeat right #ddd;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add the following line to your css file.

```
select{font-size:xx px; background-color:#xxx}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the product I prefer:
http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/